# Which schema.org type should be used for a forum?

Tags: html, schema.org, microformats

Neither Article or Blog seems to fit for a forum with topics and discussions. Or is Article considered for any generic post or comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Article for the topics and ItemList for the list of topics in forum according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/schemaorg-discussion/forum/schemaorg-discussion/hpvsSwTHIwQ/Hpi7iOFaCq4J) message.

Comment: And what about all the replies in a topic? Can you have Article in an ItemList? Probably not.

Comment: The documentation states: "A list of items of any sort—for example" so in theory it should be possible.

Comment: A little late to the party, but I experimented with using `Article` for a topic, and `Comment` for each of the replies. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

https://schema.org/DiscussionForumPosting seems to be the recommended solution from schema.org where they say it's for:

> A posting to a discussion forum.

They even provide a JSON_LD sample:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"DiscussionForumPosting",
  "@id":"http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/2gypch/is_schemaorg_still_a_thing/"
  "headline":"Is Schema.org still a thing?",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "haecceity123"
  },
  "interactionStatistic": {
    "@type": "InteractionCounter",
    "interactionType": "http://schema.org/CommentAction",
    "userInteractionCount": 25
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow itself uses [QAPage](https://schema.org/QAPage) for the HTML element, [Question](https://schema.org/Question) for question element [Answer](https://schema.org/Answer) for Answer elements.
Example:

```
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
    ...
    <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
        <h1 itemprop="name"><a href="...">The title of question</a></h1>
        <div role="main" aria-label="Question and answers">

             <div class="question">
                 <div itemprop="text">
                     The text of question 
                 </div>
                 <div>
                     Answers Count: <span itemprop="answerCount">2</span>
                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="answers">
                 <div itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
                     <div itemprop="text">
                         The text of answer
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div itemprop="suggestedAnswer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
                     <div itemprop="text">
                         The text of answer
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     ...
</html>
```

For more detail, you can inspect the source of available forums on the internet. And also, You can validate your structured data by [Structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).

Answer (score 0):

JSON-LD is the recommended solution for schema so I am looking for some real world examples. On the Schema website it gives a description for DiscussionForumPosting: A posting to a discussion forum.

This seems to indicate that each post in a topic should have structured data (which makes sense to me).

The example they give with the interactionStatistic property seems to indicate this is for the First forum post in a topic.

Forums are made up of categories (usually) and categories are made up of topics, and topics have 1 or more form posts each.

With DiscussionForumPosting how do we handle topics with multiple posts. Large Forum topics can have many pages and 100 plus posts