# What type should be used for a discussion forum / QnA forum

Tags: schema.org, microdata

This question has been asked here: [Which schema.org type should be used for a forum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227202/which-schema-org-type-should-be-used-for-a-forum)

But this was 2 years back - was wondering if there were any other ideas of using schema.org for a forum.

Simple layout of the forum is:

```
Question - posted by xyz - date xx/yy/zzzz
  Answer1  - posted by abc - date xx/yy/zzzz
  Answer2  - posted by def - date xx/yy/zzzz
  Answer3  - posted by ghi - date xx/yy/zzzz
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each answer could be a [`http://www.schema.org/Comment`](http://www.schema.org/Comment):

> A comment on an item - for example, a comment on a blog post. The comment's content is expressed via the "`text`" property, and its topic via "`about`", properties shared with all CreativeWorks.

The question could be the more general [`http://www.schema.org/CreativeWork`](http://www.schema.org/CreativeWork) (I don’t think that [Article](http://www.schema.org/Article) is appropriate, at least typically not).

Comment: Thanks Unor - makes sense - I will go with your recommendation - Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but it appears that discussion forums may have found their way into the schema:
http://schema.org/DiscussionForumPosting

> discussionUrl URL     A link to the page containing the comments of the CreativeWork.

Comment: can you also post some content from the link?

Answer (score 2):

(While this question is old, the answer is still as elusive)

It looks like it was proposed as http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/DiscussionSchema (The page contains a PDF link with a breakdown of the elements and an example of use)